# Java - Math with array items

Tags: java, math

Could you suggest any solution for this problem:

I have a long list with numbers. I would like to convert every item for integer. And then I would do something like this:

```
  FIRST item / SECOND item * THIRD item + FOURTH item

  5th / 6th * 7th + 8th and so on...
```

At the end I would return the results in another list which will have 4 times smaller length than the first list.

I am not sure about the whole logic of the process how to start this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
`ArrayList myNumberList = getList();//get the list

    ArrayList result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0, n = numbers.size(); i < n -3; ) {
        int a = myNumberList.get(i++);
        int b = myNumberList.get(i++);
        int c = myNumberList.get(i++);
        int d = myNumberList.get(i++);
        results.add(a / b * c + d);
    }`
```

Modified the code  done by Alnitak

Answer (score 3):

Try like this..

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> finalList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += 4) {
        int temp = 0;
        try {
            temp = list.get(i) / list.get(i + 1) * list.get(i + 2)
                    + list.get(i + 3);
            finalList.add(temp);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException exp) { // In case if your list size is not a multiple of 4

            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Final list has " + finalList.size()+" elements");
```